# It made me really laugh. vs. It really made me laugh

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, intensifiers

Someone asked me, "What is the difference between these two sentences?"

> It made me really laugh. 
>   It really made me laugh.

I'm a native speaker, and I feel like either one is grammatically fine. However, I am not exactly sure how to describe why "really" can go in either place.

So, here's my question. Are both of these grammatically correct? If so, what are the rules that apply that explain why "really" can be put in either place in that sentence.

Comment: I hope someone can explain why the first sentence _sounds wrong_ somehow, because I can't.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Yeah. I thought the same thing at first. Then I thought...well maybe I might say somerhing like that if I was trying to emphasize that something made me laugh pretty hard. At the same time, I feel like if that was the case, I'd just say, "It made me laugh hard."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of them are grammatical. "Really" can be used in either position, because it is an adverb modifying different verbs.

> It made me *really* **laugh**.

"Laugh" is the verb that is being modified. This sentence means that this "it" brought out from you authentic, pure laughter. The focus is on "laugh".

> It *really* **made** me laugh.

Here, "made" is the modified verb. The sentence means he succeeded at making you laugh. The focus is on the process, or "made".